# Copy data from one table to another AND set fixed values?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'm using the following SQL statement to copy data from TableA to TableB.

```
INSERT INTO TableB (url, pageViews)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) url AS url, SUM(HitCount) As pageViews
FROM TableA
WHERE (url LIKE '%www%site') AND (YEAR(dtDate) = 2011) AND (MONTH(dtDate) = 1)
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY pageViews DESC
```

At the moment, this works great at putting the url and pageViews data into TableB as below (Please ignore the dots - that was for formatting everything in line to look like a table!).

---

```
|URL            | pageViews     | ranking

|www.site.com   | 25220         | NULL

|www.site.com/a | 25230         | NULL

|www.site.com/b | 25433         | NULL
```

---

But the ranking column is NULL.  For each row I'm bringing across from TableA, I'd like to set the value of the ranking column (which only exists in TableB) to be "Top5" as below:

---

```
|URL            | pageViews     | ranking

|www.site.com   | 25220         | Top5

|www.site.com/a | 25230         | Top5

|www.site.com/b | 25433         | Top5
```

---

I'd be very grateful for any help on this.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you're using, since this isn't standard SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple as selecting the constant value for each row:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (url, pageViews, ranking)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) url AS url, SUM(HitCount) As pageViews, 'Top5' AS ranking
```

Comment: Many thanks Matti for your speedy response! It works great :)

Answer (score 1):

> But the ranking column is NULL. For
>   each row I'm bringing across from
>   TableA, I'd like to set the value of
>   the ranking column (**which only exists
>   in TableB**)

You are not selecting the `ranking` column from TableB:

```
INSERT INTO TableB (url, pageViews, ranking)
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) url AS url, SUM(HitCount) As pageViews, ranking
FROM TableA
WHERE (url LIKE '%www%site') AND (YEAR(dtDate) = 2011) AND (MONTH(dtDate) = 1)
GROUP BY url
ORDER BY pageViews DESC
```